# asp.net 4.0:Wrong loading URL

Tags: asp.net, url

Sorry i am new in ASP.NET

i have written this page, but when i run it although the **URL** in the browser is true it goes to the **Login page**. Any idea about why this happen?

The code is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="root_VerifyUsers.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="Library.Account.root" MasterPageFile="~/Root.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <p>
    <h1>

        Verify Users

    </h1>
    </p>
    <asp:Login ID="VerifyUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="accountInfo">

               <p>

                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%"></asp:ListBox>

               </p>
               <p>


               <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server"  Text="Log In" 
                 ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" onclick="LoginButton_Click" 
                       Width="691px" Height="48px"/>

               </p>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
</asp:Content>
```

code behind is :

```
namespace Library.Account
{
    public partial class root : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code behind.

Comment: @Yosi there is nothing in code behind but i add it

Comment: What is the url that you use in the browser? Can you show us it please?

Comment: Please let us know what exactly is happening, are you trying to browsing any application page but you are being redirected to login page?

Comment: @Pawan yes sir. that's it

Comment: @JasonEvans the page name is root_VerifyUsers and the url is 
**http://localhost:2166/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2froot_VerifyUsers.aspx**

Comment: Please look in to master page(if any authorisation code is writeen) or web.config as suggested by @JasonEvans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm jumping the gun here, since your question lacks a lot of information we need to answer. However, as a total stab in the dark; open up your web.config file and see if there is anything like this in there:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="Foo" loginUrl="/Login.aspx">
   </forms>
</authentication>
```

Do you have anything like the above? It could be that your website has authentication enabled which means that, since you're not logged into the site, it redirects to a login page.

EDIT:

Right, here's your problem:

`http://localhost:21266/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2froot_VerifyUsers.aspx`

Your url is actually going to `http://localhost:2166/Account/Login.aspx` which is the login page. After you login to the site, by providing a valid username and password, you will be redirected to `http://localhost:2166/Account/froot_VerifyUsers.aspx`, which is the `ReturnUrl` part of the url.

So you 100% have authentication setup in your site. My authentication setup skills are rather poor, so I can't really help you configure that. But I'm sure other SO users can help, or at least there is plenty of SO questions about ASP.NET authentication you can search through.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be showing a login page from what I can see. A log in page is what you should be getting.